# Element visible only if there are no siblings through CSS

Tags: html, css

My current code looks something like this:

```
if list.isEmpty() {
    output("<div>No items</div>")
} else {
    for each item in list
        optput("<div>" + item + "</div>")
}
```

However, the whole *"No items"* logic belongs to the *view* and should be separated from the logic. Ideally, I'd like to have just

```
for each item in list
    optput("<div>" + item + "</div>")
```

And then have the HTML template look something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div style="visible only if no siblings">No items</div>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
<div>
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do the `"visible only if no siblings"` part. Is there a way to achieve this reliably (works across all standard browsers) using CSS?

Comment: I found this article maybe it will help http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/Look-Ahead-CSS-Selectors.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give the div you want to be visible only with no siblings a particular class:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="vis-only-no-siblings">No items</div>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
<div>
```

As long as the divs have no other siblings, you'll be able to use the `:only-child` pseudoselector, like so:

```
#container div.vis-only-no-siblings{
    display: none;
}

#container div.vis-only-no-siblings:only-child {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. But if I add `<div>Item 1</div>`, won't that be covered by the first rule and be invisible?

Comment: Yes, it will be covered by the first rule, but if it has no siblings it will also be covered by the second rule, which has greater specificity - so it will end up visible.

Comment: I like this approach. I'm thinking, maybe it's better to use `display: {none, initial}` instead?

Comment: Yes, I used `visibility` as it was in your question, but think `display` might be better.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll try this out in detail and see if it all works out as intended :-)

Comment: keep in mind, that `<style>`, `<script>`, etc - though not visible - will prevent :only-child from working... only child means only child :)